# Value of strongly typed hidden field not passed to controller when set with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following view:

```
<div class="form-wrap routeDetails">

    @Html.HiddenFor(newOrder => newOrder.ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(newOrder => newOrder.WebUserID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(newOrder => newOrder.CustomerID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(newOrder => newOrder.UnregisteredCustomerID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(newOrder => newOrder.Address)
    @Html.HiddenFor(newOrder => newOrder.AddressNo)
    @Html.HiddenFor(newOrder => newOrder.ZipCode)
    @Html.HiddenFor(newOrder => newOrder.Area)
    @Html.HiddenFor(newOrder =>  newOrder.Latitude)
    @Html.HiddenFor(newOrder => newOrder.Longitude)

    <div class="center" style="margin-right:51px">
        <img id="phone" width="23px" height="23px" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/phone.png")" />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(newOrder => newOrder.Phone, new { @class = "field", style = "width: 300px;margin-left:10px", maxlength = 20 })
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div class="rcorners">

        <img id="customer" width="23px" height="23px" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/customer.png")" style="padding-right:11px"/>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(newOrder=>newOrder.Name, new { @class = "field", style = "width: 300px;", maxlength = 50 })
        <br><br>

        <img id="home" width="23px" height="23px" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/home.jpg")" style="padding-right:11px" />

       @* @Html.TextBoxFor(newOrder => newOrder.Address, new { @class = "field", @id= "Address", style = "width: 300px;", maxlength = 150 })*@
          @Html.TextBox("autocomplete")
        <br><br>

        <img id="delivComments" width="23px" height="23px" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/comment.png")" style="padding-right:11px" />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(newOrder => newOrder.DeliveryInstructions, new { @class = "field", style = "width: 300px;", maxlength = 500 })
        <br><br>

        @Html.Kendo().CheckBoxFor(newOrder=>newOrder.saveCust).Label("Αποθήκευση στοιχείων πελάτη για μελλοντική χρήση")

    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div class="rcorners2">

        <img id="value" width="23px" height="23px" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/value.png")" style="padding-right:3px"/>
        @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(newOrder => newOrder.Value).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Value dis", style = "width: 90px;" }).Min(0)

        <br><br>
        <img id="comments" width="23px" height="23px" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/comment.png")" style="padding-right:11px"/>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(newOrder => newOrder.Comments, new { @class = "field", style = "width: 300px;height: 50px",  maxlength = 500 })

    </div>
    <br><br>


</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    var options = {
        types: ['geocode'],
        region: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: { country: "GR" }
    };

    var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
    var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    places.addListener('place_changed', function () {
        var place = places.getPlace();
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {

                if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "postal_code") {
                    document.getElementById('ZipCode').value = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                }

                else if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "route") {
                    document.getElementById('Address').value = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                }

                else if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "street_number") {
                    document.getElementById('AddressNo').value = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                }

                else if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "locality") {
                    document.getElementById('Area').value = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                }

            }
        }

        document.getElementById('Latitude').value =    place.geometry.location.lat();
        document.getElementById('Longitude').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
    });



});
```

When I set the value of a hidden field using javascript I can actually see 
the value set but it is not passed to the controller and by not passed I mean it is null.On the other hand if I set the value manually on the textboxes they are passed fine.I have checked the values brought by the google api and they are returned.It's just that the values passed are null.Why is this happening??

the controller's method looks like this:

```
Public ActionResult ctlOrders_Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, OrdersViewModel newOrder, int userID)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {//do stuff}
    }


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using CityLog.Models;

namespace CityLog.ViewModels
{
    public class OrdersViewModel
    {

        //Order attributes
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Value { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> WebUserID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CustomerID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> UnregisteredCustomerID { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> BackendUserID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CallId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> inserted_at { get; set; }

        //Στοιχεία ντελιβερά
        public Nullable<int> DeliverymanID { get; set; }
        public string deliveryManName { get; set; }
        public string deliveryManPhone { get; set; }

        //Customer attributes

        public string custName { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Latitude { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Longitude { get; set; }
        public string custAddress { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryInstructions { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string AddressNo { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }

        public Boolean saveCust { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `document.getElementById` and jQuery at the same time?

Comment: I need to get the values from the google autocompleteand pass them to the view.

Comment: Show your model

Comment: In jQuery, you normally use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set or get input values.

Comment: Isn't it the same thing??

Comment: i think it's an issue of confused object `id`'s. Are you aware that the `id` for `newOrder.ZipCode` is not the same as `ZipCode` as I assume you are incorrectly using in your javascript. Another thing is `OrdersViewModel` is a `Model` and not a `Controller`. The id of `neworder.ZipCode` should be `OrdersViewModel_ZipCode`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the `JavaScript` bit of your code, it's because you've assumed the hidden field `id`'s should be as you've referenced.

Unless you've overwritten their default `id`s razor assumes that's what you want to use. Which in your case should be like the below:

```
 if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "postal_code") {
                    document.getElementById('OrdersViewModel_ZipCode').value = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                }

                else if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "route") {
                    document.getElementById('OrdersViewModel_Address').value = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                }

                else if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "street_number") {
                    document.getElementById('OrdersViewModel_AddressNo').value = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                }

                else if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "locality") {
                    document.getElementById('OrdersViewModel_Area').value = place.address_components[i].long_name;
                }
```